# Facebook authentication SSO vs WebView

Tags: android, facebook

I'm making an Android app with the Facebook SDK. I have the following questions regarding authentication.

According to the documentation of FB, if we installed the native FB app for Android and have enabled the Facebook login page of the application (FB developers panel), then our authentication uses the native FB app to authenticate and the process will be an SSO.

What if I use a WebView to authenticate Dialog? Not SSO? Is It Just OAuth? What difference does it make?

In tests I'm doing in Eclipse + ADT, not all emulators, even with the native FB app for Android, I launch this application for login (only in certain occasions, with the same source code). Would you happened to anyone?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webview dialog will do SSO (using OAuth), but the user will have to type in their username and password in the dialog. If you have the native app installed, it will ask the user to login with the Facebook app's login screen if they aren't already logged in. If the user is logged in on the Facebook app, they will not have to login again.

Comment: But we also have to put the user name in the native FB app. Is not there any other advantages to integrate login with native APP FB?

Comment: you only have to put in your username if you haven't logged in already, i think. if the user has already logged into facebook, it should use that account automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to bypass the login screen and get authenticated automatically if the user is already logged in to facebook in the Facebook app?